# How to use *ngif for [value]?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, angular5

I have below html code for add business page in ionic 3. Where I'm getting input data using `[(ngModel)]="businessData.name"`. For editing the business I used same page where I'm filling all inputs with `[value]="savedbusinessData.name"` whichever data is getting through `mybusiness api` like business name or email etc. But now editing business is working fine but when new user go to add business page I'm getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` because of `[value]="savedbusinessData.name"`. For solving this I tried `*ngIf="!savedbusinessData == ''"` using this input got disappear. So how can I use ngif here or any other solution?

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="addbusiness">

        <ion-item>
            <p (click)="addCata()">Select Category</p>
                <!-- <p class="adedcat">{{htmlContent}}</p> -->
                <ion-tags-input  [separatorStr]="','" [once]="'true'" [canBackspaceRemove]="false" [canEnterAdd]="false" [(ngModel)]="catatags" (onChange)="onChange($event)"></ion-tags-input>
            <!-- <p (click)="clearcat()">Clear All</p> -->
        </ion-item>

       <ion-item> 
        <ion-input *ngIf="!savedbusinessData == ''" [value]="savedbusinessData.name" [(ngModel)]="businessData.name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></ion-input>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item> 
        <ion-input  [value]="savedbusinessData.contact" [(ngModel)]="businessData.contact" type="number" placeholder="Contact Number"></ion-input>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item> 
        <ion-input  [value]="savedbusinessData.address" [(ngModel)]="businessData.address" type="text" placeholder="Adress"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
       <ion-item> 
        <ion-input  [value]="savedbusinessData.website" [(ngModel)]="businessData.website" type="text" placeholder="Website"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
        <ion-item> 
        <ion-input  [value]="savedbusinessData.email" [(ngModel)]="businessData.email" type="email" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
        <ion-item> 
        <ion-input  [value]="savedbusinessData.about" [(ngModel)]="businessData.about" type="text" placeholder="About"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
        <ion-item> 
        <ion-input  [value]="tags" [(ngModel)]="businessData.tags" type="text" placeholder="Tags"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>         
        <button class="busiadd" (click)="addBusiness()" ion-button>Submit</button>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: where is savedBusinessData defined and are you sure that it is set when this form is initialized

Comment: You want the input to disappear (when not valid) or not?

Comment: I want to input keep as it is for submitting new business

Comment: savedbusinessData is comming through mybusiness api but if business is not added api will return null

Comment: it just seems like savedBusinessData is undefined and thats why you are getting the error. you dont need that ngIf. you just need to make sure savedBusinessData is defined as an {} so you can bind properties to it

Comment: For a new business, what should the name be? An empty string?

Comment: for new business there us businessData.name

Comment: @user3666653 savedbusinessData only comes when User will have there business means business is already created

Comment: Try this `<ion-input [value]="(savedbusinessData && savedbusinessData.name) ? savedbusinessData.name : null" [(ngModel)]="businessData.name" type="text" placeholder="Name"></ion-input>`

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend using Angulars reactive forms. Import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the related module. Remove all `[(ngModel)]`s and put all `input`s in a form tag like this

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value)"></form>
```

Then remove the [value] properties. Add a formControlName="name" / "contact" etc. to the *input* tags. In your TS create it as follows

```js
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: '',
    contact: '',
    // ...etc
  });
}
```

When your data arrives you can simply patch the form with

```
this.myForm.patchValue(data);
```

It patches only matching attributes. Others will be ignored. Also don't forget to create a *save* function from where you can handle the form data.

```
function save(formData: YourDataType) {
  // handle formData here
}
```

Comment: How can I get input values when New business adding?

Comment: With the ngSubmit event in the form tag `<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)=save(myForm.value)></form>`. If that's what you mean.

Comment: In TS create a save function with a parameter like this `function save(data) { // handle your data here }`

Answer (score 1):

Use ?. for null check.

```
[value]="savedBusinessData?.name"
```

If you want to hide the input use..

```
<ion-item *ngIf="savedBusinessData !== undefined">
  <ion-input [value]="savedBusinessData?.name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```